# Is there other way to retrieve `code` URL parameter value provided by facebook web login dialog?

Tags: facebook

I am trying to implement custom facebook login flow with some custom 3rd party backend system that requires the `code` that's returned by facebook's **web dialog login** via the **callback's URL parameter** -

> e.g. https://calbackurl.com/?code=AsdadqwdDAWDASDwdACASdASd)

to be sent over to their end (the 3rd party backend system use the term "auth code" to describe this). But I have to use mobile facebook SDK (iOS), which does not have `response_type` option nor the `code` parameter.

How do I get this code without using the web dialog login?

I followed the guide over [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#checktoken) and [here.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing/)

Here are the things that I have tried:

1) I setup facebook login on my ios app. Trigger the login flow, and once I get the access token from the mobile SDK, I send this access token to my own API server which then call this endpoint -

> https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/client_code?access_token=...&client_id=...&client_secret=...&redirect_uri=...

to get the `code`, which I am not sure if it is the same as the `code` URL parameter provided by the web dialog login flow. After that, I send this `code` over to the 3rd party backend system. But it says the code is invalid.

2) However, when I setup the web dialog login flow for testing purpose, and manually copy the `code` from the callback's URL parameter and send it over to the 3rd party backend system, it does not return such error. And the 3rd party vendor verified that, this "code" is correct. But why it fails on 1.?

Comment: _“How do I get this code without using the web dialog login?”_ - I’m pretty sure that you simply … don’t. If you use the iOS SDK, that encapsulates that part of the login flow from you.

Comment: I don’t know where you even got that endpoint `/oauth/client_code` from, I can’t find that mentioned anywhere in the documentation - but anyway, there is no way to get a code _from_ an access token. This only works the other way around - you get the code as result of the login dialog call, and then that code can get exchanged for an access token once.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I get the oauth/client_code from the 2nd link, under "Generating Long-Lived User Tokens from Server-Side Long-Lived Tokens"

Comment: If that's the case, guess we have talk with the 3rd party vendor to find another approach for the implementation. anw, thanks for the explanation. cheers.

Comment: Ah, okay, wasn’t aware that was the token refresh endpoint. That does indeed return a code that can then be exchanged for an access token again - but that whole process is for “Generating Long-Lived User Tokens from Server-Side Long-Lived Tokens”, and with just your iOS login you only have a short-lived user token. And acquiring a long-lived one involves the app secret as well, and that should rather not be exposed in client-side code.

Comment: If you involved your own server-side component that first exchanges the short-lived iOS-acquired token for a long-lived one and then gets a code, I guess you could pass that on to the 3rd-party service afterwards. But they in turn would need to know the app secret and the redirect_uri value of the initial API call, to be able to then exchange that code for a token …